# Multi-Group AD Check with output

Tags: powershell, active-directory, wildcard

I'm trying to create a script for checking if a member of group A is not a member of groups b-g and if they are not a member of those then to output their name to a log/excel sheet - I have gotten it to output peoples names who are a member of those groups but I can't get it to return the opposite for multiple groups. If I could make an excel sheet that returns which users are part of the groups in one column and the others in another that would be great but was having issues with excel sheet output. Here's the code I've done so far. any help appreciated

```
    $logfile = "C:\Users\x\temp\outputgroupmembers.log"
    $group1 = get-adgroup group-a
    $checkgroups = Get-ADGroup -filter 'Name -like "AREA_*"' | Select-Object Name
    Foreach ($Usr In Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group1.DistinguishedName)
    {
        # If the 'MemberOf' array of $Usr's group memberships contains 'group1', then...
        If ((Get-ADUser $Usr.SamAccountName -Properties MemberOf).MemberOf -contains $checkgroups)
        {
            try{
            # output user information to document log'.
            $displayname = get-aduser $Usr.SamAccountName -Properties DisplayName | select -expand displayname
            write-output $Usr.SamAccountName $displayname >> $logfile
            }
        catch {
            write-output "Domain users group NOT output to logfile" >> $logfile
        }
    }}
```

Comment: Is there some code missing? Where is `$group` specified? And I think you have to add an other `foreach` loop to process all `$checkgroups`.

Comment: Sorry that got changed to $group1 In the code but forgot to correct before replacing the code. I tried to get a foreach-object in the code after the -contains but might not be doing it right. I tried to do -contains foreach-object ($checkgroups) but it threw errors, that line of the code is only area I can't get it to work right, I can get results if I change to a single group as either a contains or a notcontains but I'm afraid I might need to spread it out and expand it to every single group in its own line of code which would be a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this snipped. I modified your code and added the second foreach loop.
Might this helps to solve your task.

```
[System.String]$InputADGroup = 'group-a'
[Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADGroup[]]$ADGroupsToCheck = Get-ADGroup -Filter 'Name -like "AREA_*"'

foreach ($Member in (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $InputADGroup)) #Process each member of the input ad group
{
    #Get MemberOf from user
    [System.String[]]$MemberOfGroups = (Get-ADUser -Identity $Member.SamAccountName -Properties MemberOf).MemberOf

    #Check each MemberOf group
    foreach ($MemberOfGroup in $MemberOfGroups)
    {
        #Check if user is member of one of the check groups
        if ($ADGroupsToCheck.DistinguishedName -contains $MemberOfGroup)
        {
            Write-Output -InputObject ('User ' + $Member.SamAccountName + ' is member of ' + $MemberOfGroup)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sadly I can't seem to get that script to output for some reason, but I did get one from another post on reddit I made that will work for my needs even though it isn't a perfect solution it is good enough. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I got to work from another post I made of same question on reddit if anyone has similar trouble

```
$ReferenceGroup = Get-ADGroupMember BBB
$GroupList = @('CCC')
$Output = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]
foreach ($User in  $ReferenceGroup) {
    $MemberObject = [pscustomobject]@{
            Name = $User.name
    }
            foreach ($Group in $GroupList) {
            if ((Get-ADGroupMember $Group)-match $User){
                $MemberObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $Group -Value Yes
            }
            else {
                $MemberObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $Group -Value No
            }
        }
    $Output.Add($MemberObject)
}
$Output | Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\Public\test.csv
```